# GoNCurses refresh background window after foreground window moves

Tags: go, ncurses

I am trying to understand how does `ncurses` work. Here is one example I am struggling to understand and make it work.

First the idea:

- Window 1 (`stdscr`) with background and printed text
- Window 2 (`sWin`) over Window 1 with different background
- Moving Window 2 over Window 1

And here is the setup:

```
stdscr, _ := gc.Init()
defer gc.End()
gc.Echo(false)
gc.Cursor(0)
gc.CBreak(true)

stdscr.SetBackground('#')
stdscr.MovePrint(12, 15, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ...")
stdscr.NoutRefresh()

y, x := 10, 20
sWin, _ := gc.NewWindow(4, 8, y, x)
sWin.Keypad(true)
sWin.SetBackground('.')
sWin.Box(0, 0)
sWin.NoutRefresh()
gc.Update()
```

And a very simple `for` loop that will help with moving the foreground window:

```
main:
for {
    // stdscr.Erase()
    // stdscr.NoutRefresh()
    sWin.MoveWindow(y, x)
    sWin.NoutRefresh()

    gc.Update()
    switch sWin.GetChar() {
    case gc.KEY_RIGHT:
        x++
    case gc.KEY_DOWN:
        y++
    case 'q':
        break main
    }
}
sWin.Delete()
stdscr.Delete()
```

Now when I move `window 2` the one in the background does not refresh and a trail is left:

```
##########################
#######┌┌┌┌┌──────┐#######
#######│││││......│#######
##ABCDE│││││......│...####
#######└└└└└──────┘#######
##########################
##########################
```

When I uncomment `stdscr.Erase()` and `stdscr.NoutRefresh()` I fix the trail but of course I lose all the data on the background window such as the text `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ..."`:

```
#####################
#######┌──────┐######
#######│......│######
#######│......│######
#######└──────┘######
#####################
#####################
```

I tried making `Window 2` a sub window of the main one but it did not work. How can I fix/handle this? And how are overlapping windows managed in general with `ncurses`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curses doesn't support that directly (see the [panel](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/panel.3x.html) library.  Otherwise, you'll have to use [`touchwin`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_touch.3x.html) as a workaround (done with `dialog` and `cdk`).

Comment: That's great! It was exactly what I needed. I guess it is not very optimal but swill works perfectly. Thanks!